# efficiently flatten multiple columns into a single row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I efficiently "flatten" multiple columns of a dataframe into a single row?

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'a' | 'b' |
| 2 | 'c' | 'd' |

To:

| A_1 | A_2 | B_1 | B_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'a' | 'c' | 'b' | 'd' |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create `Series with MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), convert to `DataFrame` and transpose, last flatten `MultiIndex`:

```
df = df.unstack().to_frame().T
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')
print (df)
   A_1  A_2  B_1  B_2
0  'a'  'c'  'b'  'd'
```